# Writing and accessing app files on iOS devices

Tags: c, ios, file, fopen, pcap

I have a program which generates its own Wireshark pcap-file (sort of a network log if you havnt used it before). My app uses ANSI-C code to do this. 
In Android and Windows I simply use 'fopen' and 'fwrite' etc to write file to disc.

How does this work on iOS?
What is the filepath I will supply to fopen? For example in Android I use "/sdcard" or similiar, what is it here?
How do I actually extract the file afterwards from my iOS device?

EDIT: I need to use ANSI-C explicitly; all the writing is done in C libraries used in my iOS app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally use `fopen` (I use it in cross-platform code). You do however want to use `[documentPath fileSystemRepresentation]`.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS the document directory path can be found with this code:

```
NSArray  *documentDirList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir  = [documentDirList objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName"];
```

The Objective writing method might be:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:length];
[data writeToFile:documentPath atomically:YES];
```

To use "C" methods such as fopen get the char based string:

```
const char *cDocumentPath = [documentPath cStringUsingEncoding:encoding];
```

where `encoding` might be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` or another supported encoding.

Comment: sorry if I wasnt clear, I need to use 'fopen' because it is in C libraries used on ios

Comment: Added example to get the char based path, is this what you need?

Comment: Once you write the files, how can you access them though? Through Itunes somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can access them through iTunes is you specify the capability (`UIFileSharingEnabled`) in the info.plist file.  See [File and Document Support](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html)

Comment: You do not happen to know if there is any troubles using fopen to write to that location? no securty settings needed enabled or such?

Comment: I have not done that but I see no reason there would be a problem.